# Jquery dialog load mvc partialview a second time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jquery-dialog

i have a jquery dialog, where i load a two partialview, a simple master/detail
when i come back to master after save the detail, click button not response.

i post some code:

MASTER

```
        $('#dialogActivities').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var urlList = '@Url.Action("ActivityList", "Contacts")';

            $(this).load(urlList, function ()
            {
                $(".k-grid-ActivityEdit").bind("click", function ()
                {
                    var grid = $("#gridYear").data("kendoGrid");
                    var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                    if (selectedData)
                    {
                        var urlEdit = '@Url.Action("ActivityEdit", "Contacts")';
                        $('#dialogActivities').dialog().load(urlEdit);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

DETAIL

```
$(document).on('submit', '#frmActivityEdit', function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result)
        {
            if (result.success)
            {
                var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
                var urlList = '@Url.Action("ActivityList", "Contacts")';

                $('#dialogActivities').dialog().load(urlList);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to replace this piece of code:

```
$(".k-grid-ActivityEdit").bind("click", function ()
            {
                var grid = $("#gridYear").data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                if (selectedData)
                {
                    var urlEdit = '@Url.Action("ActivityEdit", "Contacts")';
                    $('#dialogActivities').dialog().load(urlEdit);
                }
            });
```

With this one:

```
$(document).on("click", ".k-grid-ActivityEdit", function ()
            {
                var grid = $("#gridYear").data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                if (selectedData)
                {
                    var urlEdit = '@Url.Action("ActivityEdit", "Contacts")';
                    $('#dialogActivities').dialog().load(urlEdit);
                }
            });
```

The difference is that using on function to bindning works also for dynamically added elements. It can resolve your problem.

Comment: now i have another problem, the first time i click, call right but the second time, it call twice, and third three time, it's like it take registered the event... i try with: $(".k-grid-ActivityDelete").unbind('click'); but it doesn't work

Comment: What type is the element you click? Is that button?

Comment: ok so please try to add event parameter to the function like this: function(evt) and add first line in function: evt.preventDefault(); or evt.stopPropagation();

Comment: Please also try different things with this unbinding if my previous comment doesn't work. Please use firebug or similar tool to debug your javascript. But I'm pretty sure that it must be one of those two solutions

Comment: nothing, i try, but it not work, with firebug the script it's right... '$(document).on("click", ".k-grid-ActivityDelete", function (evt)
                    {
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        evt.stopPropagation();'